# No option for switching branch in Egit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I created my own project in Eclipse (*Kepler version for Parallel Apps*) using PyDev, then pushed it to GitHub.

Now, when I try to switch branch using "switch to" in Eclipse, there is only one option: "New branch". It doesn't allow me to switch to any existing local branch or to look for remote branches. But on the other hand I can switch to another branch from command line or even from Eclipse "Repository view".

I thought it might be problem of configuration of my branches, so I created new branch on Github and downloaded project again. It was fetched, but unable to use "switch to" option.

But when I download other projects from GitHub I can switch to other branches.

Any ideas where is a problem?

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you using?  In my version (Kepler) I see _Team > Switch To... > Other..._ on the menu when I right-click. Other then pops up a list of branches.

Comment: I updated my question. What is weird, I can switch to other branches on other projects.

Comment: I assume "Switch to"  in Eclipse means you tried to goto Team->Switch To-> (in order to select the branch). It only displays the local branches which are checkout of the remote tracking branches. Checkout a local branch or use the <Other> option in the "Switch To"